# Clone Windows without deleting target drive's partition/files or formatting

Tags: disk-cloning

I need to clone Windows and a couple other directories from a live drive to a backup drive. I need to do so without rebooting, without deleting any files, without deleting any partitions and have the option to choose which directories I clone. Is there any freeware available to do this with?

Comment: Let me try to see if I understand.. you want to clone the OS, or just make duplicate copy (for backup) of specific directory of your choosing? I don't see there is a way for you to clone the OS (and everything) into a backup drive without the OS being stopped temporarily. Creating a Sync-Backup to copy specific folders is possible (on a running OS). Please clarify.

Comment: If I have to really reboot to clone Windows fine though I want to avoid that if at all possible. I used to copy the entire drive back in the days of Windows 98. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macrium Reflect does not require a reboot. However it DOES effectively format a drive and then creates two partitions. For example I coped 70GB of data using the program to a 120GB drive; when finished there was a 70GB partition and then the rest of the drive was unallocated. In the Computer Management-->Disk Management you click on the 70GB partition (or whatever size it is) and choose 'Extend Volume', doing so will *NOT* erase the data on the first partition.